obtain hexagon areas from a matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin plot
I am trying to plot mass surface density using hexbin because my input is a dataframe of thousands of points with [lon, lat, mass]
hexbin is fast and I want to generate a surface density map (in this case kg of mass per m2 of hexagon) so I use the following call to hexbin:

# rounded number of hexagons in x to have a hexagon widths of aprox 100m
nx = round(111000 * lenght_x / 100)

hb = df.plot.hexbin(
        x="lon",
        y="lat",
        C="mass",
        gridsize=nx,
        cmap="viridis",
        mincnt=3,
        ax=ax,
        reduce_C_function=np.sum,
    )

I use reduce_C_fuinction to get the sum of the mass and now I want to divide by the hexagon area but I do not find a way to calculate the exact area of the irregular hexagons that can be generated.
I only be able to obtain the centers of the hexagons following this:
    # Get hexagon centers
    pollycollection = hb.get_children()[0]
    centers = pollycollection.get_offsets()
    x_c = [p[0] for p in centers]
    y_c = [p[1] for p in centers]
    plt.plot(x_c, y_c, "x-", color="red")


Does anyone know any way to obtain the exact area?
Thank you in advance!

IIUC, you could make a Polygon from the hexbin vertices, then normalize it using the area :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))

hb = ax.hexbin(
    x="lon",
    y="lat",
    C="mass",
    data=df,
    gridsize=10,
    cmap="viridis",
    mincnt=3,
    reduce_C_function=np.sum,
)

from shapely import Polygon
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

hb_array_n = hb.get_array() / Polygon(hb.get_paths()[0].vertices).area
norm = mcolors.Normalize(vmin=hb_array_n.min(), vmax=hb_array_n.max())

hb.set_norm(norm)
hb.set_array(hb_array_n)

cb = plt.colorbar(hb, label="Surface Density")  # colorbar=True/pandas


Used input :
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

N = 10_000

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "lon": np.random.uniform(-180, 180, N),
        "lat": np.random.uniform(-90, 90, N),
        "mass": np.random.exponential(100, N),
    }
)

